# Discord js - client.users.cache.get('id') returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I may just simply not understand how this works, but I am trying to obtain user information using their user ID, however the variable is coming up with 'undefined'

`const user = client.users.cache.get(userId);`

I'm trying to setup a birthday scheduler for my discord channel where it will announce to a text channel a user's birthday on the specific day. I actually just basically copied this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64000129/discord-bot-send-birthday-message) to test it out. It works fine for the most part, however it just will not obtain the user information. It has not problem obtaining the text channel info using client.channels.cache.get('textchannelID');

I'm guessing it's because I'm trying to obtain information that doesn't exist yet? Because this code start when the bot starts. I have tried using things like client.guilds.cache.get("serverid") to obtain info on the server, however the only member that appears using that is the bots member ID.

I think I just don't get how the client.users.cache.get collection works. Perhaps someone could explain to me what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-and-my-functions-are-timin) The problem is that the user cache is starting empty because you don't have the required intents enabled. Furthermore, you might have to use [`client.users.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch) instead of `client.users.cache.get()` (which will also require the correct intents)

Comment: That's what it was. Thank you so much!