# cannot read property 'tag' of undefined, discord.js economy

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a problem with my code, I get the following error: `Cannot read property 'tag' of undefined`. I hope you can help me. :)

```js
if(message.content.toLowerCase() === `${prefix}rich` || message.content.toLowerCase() === `${prefix}lb` || message.content.toLowerCase() === `${prefix}leaderboard`) {
            let money = db.all().filter(data => data.ID.startsWith(`wallet`)).sort((a, b) => b.data - a.data)
            money.length = 10
            var finalLb = ""
            for(var i in money) {
                finalLb += `**${money.indexOf(money[i])+1})** ${client.users.cache.get(money[i].ID.slice(6)).tag} :- \`$${money[i].data.toLocaleString()}\`\n`
            }
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor(`Global LeaderBoard`, client.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
            .setTimestamp()
            .setColor('RANDOM')
            .setDescription(`
${finalLb}
            `)
            message.channel.send(embed)
        }
```

Comment: Like the error message says in this part `client.users.cache.get(money[i].ID.slice(6)).tag` the `get` returns `undefined` and so `tag` can not be accessed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64587139/discord-js-client-users-cache-getid-returning-undefined?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I believe is happening is that the user you're looking for hasn't been cached yet and so you're getting `undefined` instead of the user.

This can be fixed by replacing `${client.users.cache.get(money[i].ID.slice(6)).tag}` with the following which will fetch the user from all available users instead:

```
${(await client.users.fetch(money[i].ID.slice(6))).tag}
```

Please note that you will have to do this inside an asynchronous function (a function with the keyword `async`) though or, if you prefer, you can also use the `.then()` function on the `Promise` returned by the `fetch` function.

I would also recommend that you add some sort of error handling just in case this operation still fails since it still can however I believe what I mentioned above is the main reason that your code isn't working.